# mongoDB ERROR: (connection <monitor> to 3.6.21.162:27017 closed)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image]Just started learning mongoDB. I am unable to connect my cloud cluster/database to the mongoDB compass software. It gives the same error again and again (connection  to 3.6.21.162:27017 closed)

I searched in google forums but everyone's problem was solved by whitelisting their ip address. I did the same I added my ip address but its not connecting yet. I checked my username and password also. Everything correct. Please anyone help[image: My ip whitelisted in mongodb it auto added my ip]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution just add this ip address in your white list[image]